# Best way for the user to interact with textfields swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

As I was building a kind of form where the user will be able to enter informations via textfields.

I was wondering if there is a simple way to **make this form more interactive by making it scrollable.**

I know some people use scroll views, but **is it also common practice to use Collection views, or tables views and insert the textfields within the cells ? How ?**

*Which way do you personally use and how ?*

(Note that I am doing all of that programmatically without using the interface builder)

Here is a screenshot of the form I want to build:

[Form I want to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea2Sq.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**I highly recommend using [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka), You can make Swift crafted forms within minutes.**

[image]

To create a form

1. `Import Eureka`
2. Create new `UIViewController` inherited from `FormViewController`
3. ... Start adding rows in `ViewDidLoad`

   ```
   import Eureka

   class MyFormViewController: FormViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       form +++ Section("Section1")
           <<< TextRow(){ row in
               row.title = "Text Row"
               row.placeholder = "Enter text here"
           }
           <<< PhoneRow(){
               $0.title = "Phone Row"
               $0.placeholder = "And numbers here"
           }
       +++ Section("Section2")
           <<< DateRow(){
               $0.title = "Date Row"
               $0.value = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0)
           }
   }
   }
   ```

You can find more information on github.
Creating custom cells or overriding Eureka cells style is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

IQKeyboardManager is the best i am using in my every projects, I will highly recommend you to use easy and accurate solution.[IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 3rd party libraries, try using the already provided APIs by `Apple`.

There can be multiple solutions to this,

1. Use a combination of `UIScrollView` and `UIStackView`. In this case you need to create the UI of all the form fields manually (even if the UI is exactly same)
2. Use `UITableView` to create as many fields you want with a single UI.

The form that you're trying to create contains 3 fields with the same UI - only the text differs.

Since `UITableView` works on the concept of `reusability` and our form contains same type of content, we can definitely use a `UITableView`. Even if the form contains other content types as well, in that case also `tableView` is a good choice.

**1.** First of all create an `enum - FormField`, that will represent the type of a single field in the form.

```
enum FormField {
    case websiteName
    case websiteLink
    case password

    var title: String? {
        var str: String?
        switch self {
        case .websiteName:
            str = "Website's name"
        case .websiteLink:
            str = "Link"
        case .password:
            str = "Password"
        }
        return str
    }

    var placeholder: String? {
        var str: String?
        switch self {
        case .websiteName:
            str = "ex: \"Facebook\""
        case .websiteLink:
            str = "ex: \"www.facebook.com\""
        case .password:
            str = "current password"
        }
        return str
    }
}
```

We'll be using this `enum` to populate our custom UITableViewCell. You can add more field types as per your requirement.

**2.** Create a custom `UITableViewCell`

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    func configure(with field: FormField) {
        self.label.text = field.title
        self.textField.placeholder = field.placeholder
    }
}
```

**3.** Conform the `ViewController` to `UITableViewDataSource` and implement the methods

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    let formFields: [FormField] = [.websiteName, .websiteLink, .password]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.formFields.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.configure(with: self.formFields[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

In the above code, we've created a `formFields` array that we'll be using as `dataSource` to `tableView`. Add more to it as per your requirement.

[image]